# Получить данные каждой строки таблицы

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatable

Всем привет!

Есть таблица DataTables .

Каждая строка имеет  `input , select, textarea`  
Мне нужно в цикле пройти каждую строку и применить  к ней `$('input,select,textarea').serialize();` , чтобы поочередно отправлять в обработку на сервер.

Но у меня ничего не выходит, обхожу циклом, но получаю для каждой строки данные всей таблицы.

https://jsfiddle.net/uh7s93oc/1/

Comment: `$('input,select,textarea').serialize();` не сработает, почитайте [статью](https://itchief.ru/lessons/javascript/jquery-serialize-form).

Comment: @Quazimorda  , да, Вы правы. Уже разобрался, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Решение выглядит так:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  var table = $('#example').DataTable();

  $('#frm-example').on('submit', function(e){


    e.preventDefault();

    var numberOfRows = table.data().length;
    console.log(numberOfRows)

    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
      const trElem = table.row(i).node();
      const $rowControls = $('input,select,textarea', trElem);
      const serialized = $rowControls.serialize();
      console.log(serialized);
  
    }


    $('#example-console-form').text('Success');
  });      
});
```